# iOS: CGContextStrokePath with continual updates to path

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am wanting to build a small line graph that get updated when I call my `setPointInGraph:` method. Each time I call that, I want the graph to be updated with the point that I just added, and therefore draw a line from my last point.  I see the problem in my code below, in 'drawRect:' that it just keeps overwriting the old path.

```
- (void)setPointInGraph:(float)p {

    self.point = p;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
    CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

    CGColorRef strokeColor = [self.lineColor CGColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);                
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, maxY - maxY * self.point);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, maxX * (point / count), maxY - maxY * self.point);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    count++;

}
```

How can I keep the path around (such as a property) and update it when I choose to?  How can I continually add to this path not overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIBezierPath`. You can add new segments by calling `addLineToPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a path in the graphics context, create a regular path which you then stroke:

```
path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, ...);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddPath(path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

When you need to update the path, create a mutable copy of the previous path, and add the line to it:

```
path = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(lastPath);
CGPathRelease(lastPath);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, ...);
```

And then draw it again:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddPath(path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: So, what is the consensus here?  One poster suggested UIBezierPath, which is better?

Comment: Your own implementation only used Quartz drawing commands, so if you want to keep using only Quartz, use my solution. It also has the advantage that you can easily use it when drawing a Core Animation layer.

Comment: Absolutely, you can use 'CGPath'. However, working with 'UIBezier' path may be more convenient, because it is an object, not a bunch of C functions. If you need 'CGPath' you can always use 'UIBezierPath.CGPath' property.